# SOLR (3.1+) - Multiple Spatial Queries with OR in Same Request

Tags: solr, spatial

Is it possible to conduct multiple spatial queries within the same SOLR (3.1+) request?

We currently have a need to allow user to search for inventory with a location of their choice via a frontend search form. But we want to also add another spatial search behind the scenes so it will include more inventory. The resulting search would result in a venn diagram type of search.

Edit 10.4.2011

Example construct: q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=Location&(ClientId:"client1"&pt=40.68063802521456,-74.00390625&d=80.4672)%20OR%20_query_:(ClientId:"client2"&pt=36.1146460,-115.1728160&d=80.4672)

The above construct does not work, but hopefully demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What did you end up doing?  I'm facing a similar situation where I need to geospatially search an index across multiple locations.

Comment: Honestly, it's been so long I don't even remember. Got moved onto another project and haven't been back since.

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but it doesn't seem like it ever got a full answer. I had the same issue and found that this syntax works:

```
q =*:*& fq = (({
            !geofilt sfield = Location pt = 40.68063802521456,
            -74.00390625 d = 80.4672
        }
            AND ClientId : "client1")OR({
            !geofilt sfield = Location pt = 36.1146460,
            -115.1728160 d = 80.4672
        }
            AND ClientId : "client2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you like to run N querys in one request in order to get one result set per query?!

So Field Collapsing ( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing ) is what you are looking for. Unfortunately FieldCollapsing is only available from 3.3.

Depending on your needs, maybe counted results from different faceted searches could be also useful?!

Comment: Thanks for the response, it appears my question was a little vague. I updated with an example construct. I am going to take a look at fieldCollapsion however.

Answer (score 0):

What if you moved your second location query into an additional filter query, like below:

`q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=Location&(ClientId:"client1"&pt=40.68063802521456,-74.00390625&d=80.4672)&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=Location&(ClientId:"client2"&pt=36.1146460,-115.1728160&d=80.4672)`

Will that provide the results that you are looking for? It might end up being too limiting, but thought it was worth trying.

You might also try:

`q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=Location&((ClientId:"client1"&pt=40.68063802521456,-74.00390625&d=80.4672)%20OR%20(ClientId:"client2"&pt=36.1146460,-115.1728160&d=80.4672))`

Comment: I will give them a shot. Thanks for the input.